# When I render, it just shows the render and it says it's finished, but there's nothing there

Tags: rendering

When I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to render, a screen (see 2nd image) just pops up, and nothing happenes. It acts as if it's finished, when it's really not.

Is there something I've done wrong?

[image: before rendering]

[image: "rendering"[![][2]]

[image]

Comment: Check Render Layers maybe?

Comment: @LukeD I don't see any different with it, only one layer, the basic "RenderLayer" one

Comment: I can't tell why then from just screenshots. Strip down the blend file to just one object and upload it to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and I'll have a look.

Comment: OK, done @LukeD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview:

> First of all, I don't know anything about Video Editing in Blender.

**First option:**

It seems that you have some **Strip** (4.) added to the project and this is blocking/muting rendering.

1. Go to **Video Editing**.
2. **Select Strip** (if you see transparent render result hit <kbd>ESC</kbd>).
3. **Erase Strips**.

Or modify it accordingly to your project.

[image: Overview]

**Second option:**

If you don't use **VSE** at all and made this **Strip** by accident you can always turn of **Sequencer** completely:

[image]